# Customisation RecyclerView animations with DefaultItemAnimator

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, animator

I want to change the animation when the RecyclerView element is removed, namely, the element being removed changes its size from 100 percent to zero and becomes transparent, and the elements under it, after it becomes invisible, rise up and occupy the freed space. I set the animation for the disappearing element through the xml file through the Animator, but I have problems with overriding the DefaultItemAnimator methods. I tried to override the animateDissapearance method, but it looks like animateChange does all the magic.